# How to avoid reaching the youtube api call limit

Tags: server, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm building a web app and a restful API proxy server using the MEAN Stack (angular, nodejs, express, mongodb) the proxy server will be fetching some videos from my YouTube channel using the YouTube API V3 and send a json object to the client, to list all the videos from the channel. the app will support pagination so i was wondering what are some tricks that i could implement on server/client side to avoid reaching the API call limit.

i was thinking of making a request to the youtube server once and save all the data that i need for my application in a database and work with them because i 
 wont be uploading very often. I need some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Youtube's API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

Different types of operations have different quota costs.

> - A simple read operation that only retrieves the ID of each returned    resource has a cost of approximately 1 unit.
> - A write operation has a cost of approximately 50 units.
> - A video upload has a cost of approximately 1600 units.

Since all you're doing is retrieving your channels video listings, this would come under the first option, **a simple read operation**.

You also automatically receive a quota of 10,000 units a day.

> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota
>   allocation of 10 thousand units per day, an amount sufficient for the
>   overwhelming majority of our API users

From this info, I'd say that you don't need to worry about hitting the API limit, as your use case seems quite light!